# Circle inversion of a circle

Tags: geometry, circles, inversive-geometry

Given is a circle K with radius r and centre M1. K' is a second circle with radius r' and centre M2 that cuts K in two points A and B so that $[M1A]$ is orthogonal to $[M2A]$ and also $[M1B]$ is orthogonal to $[M2B]$. 
We noted:

- Now through inversion on K, every circle K' is being reflected onto itself.

**Why is this so?**

We also noted that a circle conversion of a line gives a line again. Again: why a line and not a circle? Trying to visualize it I get an arc..
[image]

Comment: This is completely wrong.

Comment: Inversion with which centre? which radius?

Comment: Inversion with centre of K. More it does not say.

Comment: By middlepoints, you mean centers of the circles?

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes, exactly. I should correct this above!

Comment: @darijgrinberg the thesis should now be correct, right?

Comment: As to the line issue: It's true that inversion of **a line through the center of inversion** is the same line (with its points rearranged). Lines not-through the center of inversion become circles through that center. (Just think about how the center of inversion and the point at infinity have to exchange places.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding a proof of the proposition, consider the following diagram:

[image]

So we are given:

- The triangle formed by the two centres and $A$ is right. Algebraically $d^2=r^2+r'^2$.
- $C$ is a random point on the second circle with inversion $C'$. $D$ is their midpoint. So $C,C'$ lie at distances $q+t,q-t$ from $M_1$ respectively.
- $C,C'$ being inversions means that $(q+t)(q-t)=r^2$.

We are two show that:

- $C'$ lies on the blue circle iff $C$ does.
- This is equivalent to saying that the midpoint $D$ is placed in a way so that the dotted line $s$ meets the segment $C' C$ at a right angle.
- In other words, $s$ must divide the triangle formed by the two centres and the point $C$ into two right triangles.
- So if we can show that $d^2-q^2=s^2=r'^2-t^2$, we are done.

The steps to show this are:

- From earlier on we have: $r^2=(q+t)(q-t)=q^2-t^2$.
- Substituting this expression for $r^2$ into the equation $d^2=r^2+r'^2$ and subtracting $q^2$ from both sides leads to the desired goal.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 3):

I think this is the situation:

[image: pic1]
[image: pic2]

As you can see the inversion of any point *C* on *K'* is a point *F* which is also on *K'*.

Comment: Thank you! How did you do it? Would you mind sending me the ggb-data? :)

Comment: Sorry, I did not save it. I created the red circle, then added a point outside of it for $M_2$. I took the tangent lines from that point and marked the tangent points $A$ and $B$. The blue circle goes through those points. Tangent lines are orthogonal to radial lines. To get the green points, I picked an arbitrary point on the blue circle and drew tangent lines to the red circle. Finally the inversion is on the midpoint between $D$ and $E$.